# How do you update a field if it is null in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, null

I have a field named `size`. Some rows are `null`. I want to update these rows' `size` field to `0`. How I'll do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update tablename
set    size = 0
where  size is null;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET size = 0
WHERE size IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to use `WHERE size IS NULL` in the update clause:

```
UPDATE table SET size = 0 WHERE size IS NULL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLENAME 
SET SIZE=0
WHERE SIZE IS NULL;
```